# Python histogram of split() data

Tags: python, matplotlib, split, histogram

I am trying to make a histgramm over a text file containing floats:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c1_file = open('densEst1.txt','r')
c1_data =  c1_file.read().split()    
c1_sum = float(c1_data.__len__())

plt.hist(c1_data)
plt.show()
```

The output of `c1_data.__len__()` works fine, but `hist()` throws:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/x.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/x.py", line 7, in <module>
    plt.hist(c1_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2958, in hist
    stacked=stacked, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1812, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5995, in hist
    if len(xi) > 0:
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: how does look your data ?

Comment: It does not make sense to compute a histogram of a single number. Please provide a complete problem description including what you are trying to achieve. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Why would you think it's a single number?

Comment: As I said, it is a text file containing floats :) separated by spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason the `plt.hist` call fails is because the argument `c1_data` is a list containing strings. When you `open` a file and `read` it [the result will be a string](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) containing the files contents:

> To read a file’s contents, call `f.read(size)`, which reads some quantity of data and returns **it as a string (in text mode)** or bytes object (in binary mode).

Emphasis mine.

When you now [`split`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) this long string you'll get a list containing strings:

> Return a list of the words in the string, using *sep* as the delimiter string.

However a list of strings is not a valid input for `plt.hist`:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.hist(['1', '2'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 2 plt.hist(['1', '2'])

C:\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3079                       histtype=histtype, align=align, orientation=orientation,
   3080                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, label=label,
-> 3081                       stacked=stacked, data=data, **kwargs)
   3082     finally:
   3083         ax._hold = washold

C:\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1895                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1896                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1897             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1898         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1899         if pre_doc is None:

C:\...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in hist(***failed resolving arguments***)
   6178             xmax = -np.inf
   6179             for xi in x:
-> 6180                 if len(xi) > 0:
   6181                     xmin = min(xmin, xi.min())
   6182                     xmax = max(xmax, xi.max())

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

### The solution:

You can simply convert it to a float-array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> plt.hist(np.array(c1_data, dtype=float))
```

Comment: thanks. didn't read the doc of split() carefully enough and thought it would cast them already

Comment: @Yannik You're welcome. You could also try using [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html): `c1_data = np.loadtxt('densEst1.txt')`. It may require some fiddling with the parameters but when it works it will automatically read the file, split it and convert it to an array. :) But I don't know how your dataset looks like (one line containing the values, or one value per row or something else entirely), that's why I didn't include it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pointing  to an example using *numpy* ... easy and results are below with the code.

*pandas* will work too, split and data type are available on reading (even if is a column data), also you can read as a *vector* (depends of the size of data)/

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np

# will be better to read with numpy because you use float ...
#a = np.fromfile(open('from_file', 'r'), sep='\n') 

from_file = np.array([1, 2, 2.5]) #sample data a
c1_data = from_file.astype(float) # convert the data in float

plt.hist(c1_data)  # plt.hist passes it's arguments to np.histogram
plt.title("Histogram without 'auto' bins")
plt.show()
```

[image: without auto bins]

```
plt.hist(c1_data, bins='auto')  # plt.hist passes it's arguments to np.histogram
plt.title("Histogram with 'auto' bins")
plt.show()
```

[image: with 'auto' bins]